# Transformations for a [0,1] covariate in polynomial regression

Tags: regression, data-transformation, skewness

I have a polynomial regression in the form of $y = a + b_1x_1 + b_2x_1^2 + b_3x_2 + ...$

I am interested in the interpretation of the regression coefficients, specifically if the relationship of $y$ with $x_1$ given other X's is U shaped or upside down U shaped, and for what values of $x_1$ will the impact be positive.  I have found that $b_1 < 0$ and $b_2 > 0$ so it is U shaped and this makes sense in application.

However, $x_1$ is only defined on the interval $[0,1]$.  From the regression equation $dy/dx_1$ will only start to become positive when $x_1 > 1.6$, so while it is U shaped $x_1$ can never have a positive impact on $y$.  From knowledge of the application I cannot say this is impossible though it certainly feels counter intuitive. One thing I have observed about the data is that $x_1$ is extremely skewed, with a large concentration of values in the $[0,0.1]$ interval and another chunk in the $[0.9,1.0]$ interval.  Are there transformations that are suitable for this type of skew under a polynomial regression?  I am very interested in any mathematical explanation

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by transforming $x_1$?

Comment: Rather than being skewed, x1 sounds bimodal.  That should affect decisions about transformation.  Please show the univariate distributions and the bivariate y~x1 distribution (either with or without other variables controlled) in order to obtain the most informed responses from this community.